# i3wm loosing focus when going back to intelij

Tags: i3-wm

It's really weird, but if I use keyboard in i3 wm (all on default configuration) and I use keyboard to switch from chrome to webstorm, there is no cursor focus in webstorm. If I go back to chrome, focus is there. I tried Idea and PhpStorm and it behaves the same. Going to chrome, retains the focus, but going back to IDE, looses it again, so I need to click with mouse every time I go back to IDE.

Any pointers on how to fix it will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a behaviour called `focus follow mouse` You can disable it in the config file - more here : https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_focus_follows_mouse